# Integral involving Airy function and its Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, airy-functions

I would like to evaluate the following function analytically

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ds \text{Ai}(s)e^{2\pi i s x}e^{\frac i 3 (2\pi s)^3}$$

I know from evaluating this numerically that the answer is of the form

$$c_0\text{Ai}(x)+c_1\text{Ai}'(x)$$

but I do not understand why.

Note that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ds e^{2\pi i s x}e^{\frac i 3 (2\pi s)^3}=\text{Ai}(x)$$

Another potentially useful feature of the Airy function is orthogonality.

Comment: Are you integrating for $s$ from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$?

Comment: @the_candyman yes, sorry should have specified!

Comment: I don't want to dismiss the numerical evidence, but I'm also a little skeptical that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} ds \mathrm{Ai}(s) e^{2 \pi i s x} e^{\frac{i}{3} (2 \pi s)^3}$ would have the form $c_0 \mathrm{Ai}(x) + c_1 \mathrm{Ai}'(x)$. This seems equivalent to saying that the Fourier transform of the latter is $\mathrm{Ai}(s) e^{\frac{i}{3} (2 \pi s)^3}$, when in fact it's a degree-one polynomial in $s$ times $e^{\frac{i}{3} (2 \pi s)^3}$. But maybe there's a subtlety in how the integrals should be interpreted here. Can you say more about the numerical evidence that you have?

Comment: @Jason I see what you mean. The numerical evidence I have is that when you evaluate the integral in Mathematica, and plot the real and imaginary part you get a clear Ai function for the real part, and a clear Ai' for the imaginary part, with some scaling on the y axis only

Comment: @Jason upon a closer look it looks like the solution is really of the form: $c_0 Ai(x) + c_1 x Ai(x) + c_2 x^2 Ai(x) + d_0 Ai'(x) + d_1 x Ai'(x) + d_2 x^2 Ai'(x) + ...$ with the $c_0$ and $d_0$ coefficients an order of magnitude larger than the trailing coefficients. So I guess it is actually some exponential term instead

Comment: @Cameron Hmm, that's interesting. I've been curious - I see that you've asked some related questions over the past couple months. What's the context where this integral is coming up?